# Can we add a comment column next to the Change column in Audit View of EA?

Tags: enterprise-architect

1. Is there a provision to store user entered comment during modification to the “Model” which can be shown in the “Audit View” along with “Original” and “CHANGE” columns of EA.
2. Can we add a comment column next to the Change column in Audit View of EA, where user entered comment can be stored. Please suggest the EA API to do the same.

Comment: I think you are barking up the wrong tree. Audit entries are stored for each and every single change. Making the user enter a comment for each change would make using the tool simply impossible.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not easily do that. You might modify the underlying database and add columns to existing tables (or even add your private tables). But that would break XMI export as these columns would not be ex-/imported and you're on your own to maintain this. An alternative is to use tagged values in general cases. But here I doubt it's feasible. So probably your own table with foreign key referring the audit would be the choice. However, it merely sound like you're trying to re-build a check-in mechanism. FWIW: in practice I found this mechanism counter-productive as people tend to comment either nothing or trivialities. So that it hinders more than it helps.
2. You can not modify the standard dialogs (e.g. fo the shown audit view). That means you have to write an add-in to create your own dialog.

The table that contains the audit is `t_snapshot`.

Comment: I tried to find it in the schema but, I was unable to find where the table is getting created for “Auditing”.

Can you please tell me where will I find the existing table for “Audit View”.

Comment: Thank you, Can you tell me what is that alternative way of using tagged values in general cases as mentioned above. Is that a MDG or any other way of creating tagged values to fetch this requirement.

Comment: Well, it depends on the use case. For auditing it's probably not that useful as TVs will appear with each element in masses (depending on the change frequency). You would in any case need to write an add-in to create those TVs. Sorry, but discussing the use of that would simply be too broad as question and definitely won't go to this comment section.